# Django + Remote User Backend

Tags: django

Помогите решить задачку.
При переходе между шаблонами слетают данные о авторизации пользователя. Для авторизации используется django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend. Вот набросок кода. Пользователь попал на index и его авторизовало. Дальше уже авторизованный пользователь переходит на photo и все, он уже not authenticated.

```
def index(request):
username = request.environ.get('HTTP_REMOTE_USER')
auth = RemoteUserBackend()
user = auth.authenticate(request, username)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth')
else:
    pass

var = user
return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'var': var}

@login_required()
def photo(request):
var = dict()
var['some_var'] = 'some data'
return render(request, 'core/gallery.html', {'vars': var})
```

Как в этом случае "передать авторизацию"  в другой шаблон?

Answer (score 1):

В файле `settings.py` прописано следующее?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    '...',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    '...',
]
```

Comment: Да, прописано как в вашем примере.

Answer (score 0):

Путем экспирементов я обнаружил причину такого поведения. Ошибка в этом участке`login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth')`

Правильный login() должен быть такой:

```
login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```